# Ajax Refresh Images Composition with Attribute Selection

Tags: product-attribute, image, ajax

I've been tasked with trying to duplicate this feature of a Shopify cart on Magento:

https://savageswim.com/collections/builder/products/custom-leggings

My manager is looking for a system that let's us apply images or skins and update only that selection when the attribute is chosen on the website.

I understand that I can do this with regular images and create an image for every possible attribute combination - but for us that is 100s of images. Hoping for a cleaner solution via extension or some other kind of programming.

Answer (score 0):

As they have set Leggings Color and Waistband as two different drop down field.

on selection of any color from this field they are simply changing the image of that field only. So that you do not have to create image for every possible attribute combination.

create Leggings and Waistband image for all the color.

in this you just have to work on its placement on respective position.

Comment: How and with what vanilla magento coding would this be possible? I have tried to create these products but they each need their own simple product sku for the configurable parent to associate with. Magento natively reloads the entire main image for the associated simple product based on the configurable products variable attributes.

Comment: You can create custom options for the field and one extra field for file path by referring http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-custom-attributes-custom-options  and then use that in frontend.